# I can't change the state of the input tag when click on submit button and when it's empty of fill with text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Here I built a form and I want, when I click on submit button 
 if title part(input with id form-title) is empty border of the input gets a specific className but 
It doesn't work 
I uploaded an image and specify the submit button and input of title
My purpose is when I click on submit button the code must check the inside of the input tag(title) and if it's empty(I mean equal to "" ) the border of the input become red else become green

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./tickets.css";

export default function Tickets() {
// States
const [toggle_new_ticket, setToggle_new_ticket] = useState(false);
const [form_title, set_form_title] = useState("");
const [form_unit, set_form_unit] = useState("");
const [form_explain, set_form_explain] = useState(false);
let [check, setCheck] = useState("");

// States functions
const form_checker = () => {
    setCheck(() => {
        if (form_title == "") {
            check = false;
        } else {
            check = true;
        }
        console.log(check);
    });
};

return (
    <div className="tickets-container">
        {/* New Ticket section */}
        <div className="tickets-new-ticket-container">
            {/* New Ticket Title */}
            <div
                className="tickets-new-ticket-title"
                onClick={(e) => {
                    setToggle_new_ticket(!toggle_new_ticket);
                }}
            >
                <div className="new-ticket-image">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-tanah-basah-glyph-tanah-basah/48/000000/external-plus-user-interface-tanah-basah-glyph-tanah-basah-2.png" />
                </div>
                <div className="new-ticket-title">
                    <sapn> ثبت درخواست جدید</sapn>
                </div>
            </div>
            {/* New Ticket Form */}
            {toggle_new_ticket ? (
                <div className="tickets-new-ticket-form-container">
                    {/* Form top container */}
                    <div className="tickets-new-ticket-form-top-container">
                        {/* Form title part */}
                        <div className="new-ticket-form-title">
                            <label htmlFor="form-title">عنوان</label>
                            <input
                                onChange={(e) => {
                                    set_form_title(e.target.value);
                                }}
                                className={check ? "form-correct" : "form-alarm"}
                                type="text"
                                name="form-title"
                                id="form-title"
                                required
                                value={form_title}
                                title="عنوان مورد نظرتان را وارد کنید"
                                {...console.log(check)}
                            />
                            <span>current state of title:{}</span>
                        </div>
                        {/* Form unit part */}
                        <div className="new-ticket-form-unit">
                            <label htmlFor="form-unit">واحد</label>
                            <select name="form-unit" id="form-unit" required>
                                <option value disabled selected className="form-unit-header">
                                    واحد مورد نظر را انتخاب کنید
                                </option>
                                <option value="پیگیری سفارش">پیگیری سفارش</option>
                                <option value="احراز هویت"> احراز هویت</option>
                                <option value="مالی">مالی </option>
                                <option value="سایر">سایر </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/* Form order part */}
                    <div className="new-ticket-form-order">
                        <label htmlFor="form-order">در خصوص سفارش</label>
                        <select name="form-order" id="form-order">
                            <option value="">هیچکدام</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    {/* Form explain part */}
                    <div className="new-ticket-form-explain">
                        <label htmlFor="form-explain">توضیحات</label>
                        <textarea
                            name="form-explain"
                            id="form-explain"
                            cols="60"
                            rows="10"
                            value={form_explain}
                            onChange={(e) => {
                                set_form_explain(e.target.value);
                            }}
                        ></textarea>
                    </div>
                    {/* ّForm upload file part */}
                    <div className="new-ticket-form-upload-file">
                        <label htmlFor="">فایل پیوست</label>
                        <label htmlFor="form-upload" className="form-upload">
                            <span>انتخاب فایل</span>
                            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/20/000000/upload.png" />
                        </label>
                        <input type="file" name="form-upload" id="form-upload" />
                        <span className="form-upload-explain">
                            پسوندهای مجاز: jpg, jpeg, png, pdf, doc, docx, zip, rar حداکثر
                            حجم فایل 5 مگابایت
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    {/* Form submit btn */}
                    <div className="new-ticket-form-submit">
                        <input
                            type="submit"
                            name="form-submit"
                            id="form-submit"
                            value="ارسال درخواست"
                            onClick={() => {
                                form_checker();
                            }}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            ) : (
                ""
            )}
        </div>
        {/* Tickets log section */}
        <div className="tickets-log-container"></div>
    </div>
);}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest you use semantic HTML for React form, such as: `<button type="submit">` instead of using an `input` inside a `div`.  
Use `<form>` tag and set `onSubmit={form_checker()}` so the form will be activated after you click the submit button.

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import "./tickets.css";
export default function App() {
    // States
    const [toggle_new_ticket, setToggle_new_ticket] = useState(false);
    const [form_title, set_form_title] = useState('');
    const [form_unit, set_form_unit] = useState('');
    const [form_explain, set_form_explain] = useState(false);
    let [check, setCheck] = useState(false);

  
    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (form_title !== '') {
        setCheck(true);
      } else {
        setCheck(false);
      }
    }, [form_title])

    return (
        <div className="tickets-container">
            {/* New Ticket section */}
            <div className="tickets-new-ticket-container">
                {/* New Ticket Title */}
                <div
                    className="tickets-new-ticket-title"
                    onClick={(e) => {
                        setToggle_new_ticket(!toggle_new_ticket);
                    }}
                >
                    <div className="new-ticket-image">
                        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/external-tanah-basah-glyph-tanah-basah/48/000000/external-plus-user-interface-tanah-basah-glyph-tanah-basah-2.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="new-ticket-title">
                        <sapn> ثبت درخواست جدید</sapn>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/* New Ticket Form */}
                {toggle_new_ticket ? (
                    <div className="tickets-new-ticket-form-container">
                        {/* Form top container */}
                        <div className="tickets-new-ticket-form-top-container">
                            {/* Form title part */}
                            <div className="new-ticket-form-title">
                                <label htmlFor="form-title">عنوان</label>
                                <input
                                    onChange={(e) => {
                                        set_form_title(e.target.value);
                                    }}
                                    className={ check ? 'form-correct' : 'form-alarm'}
                                    type="text"
                                    name="form-title"
                                    id="form-title"
                                    required
                                    value={form_title}
                                    title="عنوان مورد نظرتان را وارد کنید"
                                    {...console.log(check)}
                                />
                                <span>current state of title:{}</span>
                            </div>
                            {/* Form unit part */}
                            <div className="new-ticket-form-unit">
                                <label htmlFor="form-unit">واحد</label>
                                <select
                                    name="form-unit"
                                    id="form-unit"
                                    required
                                >
                                    <option
                                        value
                                        disabled
                                        selected
                                        className="form-unit-header"
                                    >
                                        واحد مورد نظر را انتخاب کنید
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="پیگیری سفارش">
                                        پیگیری سفارش
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="احراز هویت">
                                        {' '}
                                        احراز هویت
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="مالی">مالی </option>
                                    <option value="سایر">سایر </option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {/* Form order part */}
                        <div className="new-ticket-form-order">
                            <label htmlFor="form-order">در خصوص سفارش</label>
                            <select name="form-order" id="form-order">
                                <option value="">هیچکدام</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        {/* Form explain part */}
                        <div className="new-ticket-form-explain">
                            <label htmlFor="form-explain">توضیحات</label>
                            <textarea
                                name="form-explain"
                                id="form-explain"
                                cols="60"
                                rows="10"
                                value={form_explain}
                                onChange={(e) => {
                                    set_form_explain(e.target.value);
                                }}
                            />
                        </div>
                        {/* ّForm upload file part */}
                        <div className="new-ticket-form-upload-file">
                            <label htmlFor="">فایل پیوست</label>
                            <label
                                htmlFor="form-upload"
                                className="form-upload"
                            >
                                <span>انتخاب فایل</span>
                                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/20/000000/upload.png" />
                            </label>
                            <input
                                type="file"
                                name="form-upload"
                                id="form-upload"
                            />
                            <span className="form-upload-explain">
                                پسوندهای مجاز: jpg, jpeg, png, pdf, doc, docx,
                                zip, rar حداکثر حجم فایل 5 مگابایت
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        {/* Form submit btn */}
                        <div className="new-ticket-form-submit">
                            <input
                                type="submit"
                                name="form-submit"
                                id="form-submit"
                                value="ارسال درخواست"
                                onClick={() => {
                                    form_checker();
                                }}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    ''
                )}
            </div>
            {/* Tickets log section */}
            <div className="tickets-log-container" />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Use **UseEffect** hook , when title was changed , it will be fire , and you can make a check is title empty or not , also not need use state callback for set check value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Hakob Sargsyan But I want this happen when I click on submit button not in normal state what do you suggest ?

Comment: check this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/setstate-problem-f3vnzr)